# Calculating code churn between two specific builds in TFS

Tags: tfs

We recently began using TFS to perform our builds, and are happy with the results that we're getting from it.  One metric we're interested in is code churn.  We build the system every 2 hours, getting code churn metrics between those builds.  We also periodically manually label the system and generate a build that is consumed by our testing team.  We'd like a way to see the churn between labeled build A and labeled build B (could be as long as 4, 5 weeks), but cannot figure out how to get TFS to tell us this natively.

We have thought of one approach, but it's fairly manual - we can create a branch just for reporting purposes and build off of it, but it's not convenient; Updates are the simple case, but adds, renames, deletes would have to be dealt with manually.

Comment: Are you looking for churn # or Work Items in the new build since the last build?

Comment: Both would be ideal, but churn is what I need  including lines added, deleted, changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information using TFS_Analysis (Analysis services) & Excel.  Here's a screenshot of a Pivot Chart setup... [image]

If you need more detail, I'll queue up a blog post on how to do this.

Comment: Copy and open that picture in another tab or window to see it bigger.  Apparently SO doesn't link to the full scale image.

Comment: Hi @RyanCromwell,
Can you please let me know more information on this!